# Use Hibernate's ColumnTransformer based on the db

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I need to use my application with 2 different db. I need to encrypt the data while writing and decrypt while reading. I was thinking of using @ColumnTransformer but couldn't find how to change the sql functions as per the database.
Can anyone suggest some way to do it.
The databases to be used are mysql and oracle.

Comment: Encryption is one of those places where there isn't a common implementation between database engines, so ColumnTransformer requires custom SQL. What is the actual *requirement* for data encryption? Should the data be encrypted *at rest* in the data files, or must the data be encrypted such that other database users can't read it at all (which creates other problems, like not being able to select or index the unencrypted column values)? Could your requirement be handled with access controls in the database or native transparent data encryption, rather than in the app?

Comment: Well we did consider the data file encryption. In that case I guess Oracle provides additional capabilities like TDE to handle for us. But the main motive is to prevent users to query the data from DB and only the application to read it. I am now trying to implement a common method which internally calls the respective DB's encryption call. But still the indexing and search parts are to be considered as well.

Comment: Preventing users from reading data does not require encryption, only access restrictions.

Comment: @AdithyaR Encrypting the data values will effectively prevent searching, indexing, foreign key relationships, etc. You only want to do this on specific, non-key fields that will never be searched. The recommended approach (as Shadow suggested) is to use access controls to prevent people from seeing the sensitive tables or columns at all. For Oracle that would be tools like roles, views or PL/SQL APIs to filter access; Virtual Private Database; or even more advanced options like Advanced Security Redaction or Database Vault. There's no DB-agnostic approach. Every DB has its own thing for this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. We finally decided to not go ahead with the column data encryption due to need of indexing. Mostly will be going ahead with access restrictions and Oracle Advanced Security Suite.